# How to handle redirects in UIWebView properly?

Tags: iphone, redirect, uiwebview

how do I handle a redirect in a UIWebView properly, not mixing up the back button history?

I have a URL request (e.g. "http://www.example.com/lunch_menu.php") in a UIWebView that redirects to a weekly updated PDF File (e.g. "http://www.example.com/august_kw1.pdf").

After the redirect to the PDF file, the back button of the UIWebView contains the URL of the PHP file. If I tap on the back button, it redirects to the PDF File again, resulting in an infinite interaction loop.

I would like to know if there is any way of handling this problem in a clear way? I would like to keep the back button history of the UIWebView and not writing my own one....

Greetings,
helli99

Answer (score 4):

You could add the UIWebViewDelegate

Assign your WebView.delegate = self;

Then add this method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    if(request.URL == [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/august_kw1.pdf"])
    {

    } else {

    }

    return  YES;
}
```

And then handle your own methods there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScripts injections :

Going back :

```
[ yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"history.back();"];
```

Going forward :

```
[ yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"history.forward();"];
```

Is that helpful?

Comment: I am not sure how this could help me? Could please specify this a little bit?

Comment: You have to make your own back button and insert this code into click function. there's tutorial how to achieve that : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAdmetwz7sc   please let me know if you need any help.